# perform arithmetic operations python

Tags: python

given the number `12345 = 1x10^4 + 2x10^3 + 3x10^2 + 4x10^1 + 5x10^0`, how to perform some arithmetic operations to leave you with just the digit at position 5 (from the left) and output it to the screen? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to stick to arithmetic operations (and not strings), use the modulo operator with 10 to get the remainder of division by 10, i.e. the unit:

```
12345%10
```

output: `5`

For an arbitrary number, you need to compute the position, you can use log10 and ceil:

```
from math import log10, ceil
N = 5
number = 1234567
number//10**(ceil(log10(number))-N)%10
```

output: `5`